# I have configured all my services on docker-compose but it still says "Error establishing a database connection"

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, docker-compose, mariadb

I have a little problem.
I'm trying to launch wordpress which is itself connected to my database (mariadb) through the Nginx server. But when I enter http://localhost:8080 it says "Error establishing a database connection".

This is my docker-compose.yml :

version: '3.3'

services:

##MariaDB

mariadb:

```
container_name: mariadb
image: mariadb
volumes:
    - ./mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
  MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
  MYSQL_USER: wordpress
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
restart: always
```

##Wordpress

wordpress:

```
container_name: wordpress
image: wordpress:fpm-alpine
depends_on:
    - mariadb
volumes:
    - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
environment:
  WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
  WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
  WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
  WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
restart: always
```

##Nginx

nginx:

```
container_name: nginx
image: nginx:alpine
depends_on:
    - wordpress
volumes:
    - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
ports:
    - "8080:80"
```

This is my nginx.conf :

server {

```
listen 80;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
root /var/www/html;

location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;  
}  

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ip you have specified for mariadb is wrong:

```
container_name: wordpress
image: wordpress:fpm-alpine
depends_on:
    - mariadb
volumes:
    - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
environment:
  WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
  WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
  WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
  WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
restart: always
```

Corrected:

```
container_name: wordpress
image: wordpress:fpm-alpine
depends_on:
    - mariadb
volumes:
    - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
environment:
  WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mariadb:3306
  WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
  WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
  WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
restart: always
```